# How to build Android App GUI using KV language?

Tags: android, python-2.7, android-layout, kivy

I'm building a simple android App using Python Kivy, but I'm not able to make a simple GUI, what I'm trying to achieve is the following

- a text saying "FB"
- a user input
- a Button

I'm using `BoxLayout`, below is my KV code and the result that I got  ...
How can I make the `TextInput` above the button? Also, is there any simple Kivy GUI builder I can use?

```
Builder.load_string('''
<MyInterface>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        text: "FB"

    Label:
        TextInput:
            id: number
            size_hint_y: None
            size: (400,100)    
    IntentButton:
        size_hint_y: None
        size: (400,100)
        text: "Dial call via phone"
        on_release: self.send_sms()
    Label:

''')

class MyInterface(BoxLayout):
    pass
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detele `Label` which is a parent of the `TextInput`.

If you add a widget to another widget, which isn't a layout, it will receive a default pos of [0, 0] and default size of [100, 100] (in your case, you have overwritten it to [400, 100]).

About a GUI designer - there is an experimental one, but it isn't recommended for beginners.

Comment: That worked fine thanks, can you please refer to website or document where i can learn how to design a very basic interface using Kivy language? thanks again for your help

Comment: @clienteastwood [Kivy Designer](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer) and it seems the project is still alive. ^_^ But I recommend you only to use it for learning kv. For someone who knows kv it could be more time consuming than writing it in notepad.

Comment: @clienteastwood You could check [Kivy Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVWAKzR63ig), and [documentation (has examples)](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html).